# How to order the SQL result on all columns without specifying them individually?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, informix

Suppose my table `tabname` has **5** columns.

I want to do this :

```
select * from tabname order by col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

Instead of that, is there a way similar to this :

```
select * from tabname order by 'AllColumns'
```

With the above line, I should be able to order the results on all the columns without specifying them individually. Using the **Informix** Database?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. One way is to use [select field number](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls684.htm), but this works if columns count in the select statement is fixed (or not less than numbers you use in the ORDER BY).

For example if you have always 5 columns (or more) in the select list you can run following query:

```
  select * from tabname order by 1,2,3,4,5
```

In this example it means that `1` - is a first column in the select list, `2` is the second ,....

Comment: Thank you. I am already using `select * from tabname order by 1,2,3,4,5` I wanted something more general and you have said that we can't do it.